# How to load waymo scenario data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, tfrecord

How do I load the waymo motion scenario files (Scenario protocol buffers)?
According to the tutorial, this should work:

```
FILENAME = "uncompressed_scenario_testing_testing.tfrecord-00000-of-00150"
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FILENAME, compression_type='')
for data in dataset:
    frame = open_dataset.Frame()
    frame.ParseFromString(bytearray(data.numpy()))
    break
```

However, I get "Error parsing message".
Nevertheless, loading tf.example is no problem when utilizing:

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FILENAME, compression_type='')
data = next(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
parsed = tf.io.parse_single_example(data, features_description)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work for the scenario data, because I dont know the feature_description of the data... or I am unable to understand detailed explanation of waymo

Could somebody help me to not only load data but to understand the basic architecture of the dataset

Thanks